# How to text alignment to right when use weight for TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-layout-weight

i want to set text alignment to right when my `TextView` is set to `layout_weight` 
my application must be support old versions of android such as Android 2.2. this below layout does not set correctly alignment to right `TextView`:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/loading"
        >
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".42"/>
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="43dp"
            android:layout_weight="6"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:text="@string/please_wait_to_response_from_server"
            />
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".42"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and i'm checking this ways: set `layout_width` to `fill_parent`, `match_parent`, `wrap_contect`

Comment: Off-topic: how do you guys get such strange weights like 0.42. It's not the first time I see it. What maths beneath it? :) BTW, two fileds have weights of 0.42, and the middle one is 6. You sure there's no error? Too distinct values

Comment: any screenshot will helpful what u want ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "weight" and "layout_gravity" won't work 'cause you are telling the layout 2 different things. If you want your text to be right aligned, you can use "gravity" instead of "layout_gravity".

```
android:gravity="right"
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm having similar problems, but `android:gravity=center` still doens't work.  Any clues?